# PHP, redirect to another page

Tags: php, redirect

How in a PHP script do I redirect to another page?
I tried `header`, but this didn't work since before my header() statement is an echo.

This, I do not want to use:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;URL=?".$link."'>";
```

Comment: Why would you want to do an echo if you redirect the user anyway? You could just put the header() at the very beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use [ob_start()](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to delay the printing, and use header(), or
- Redirect using Javascript, this can be done anywhere in the page, or
- Rewrite your code so that you know early on, before anything is printed, whether you want a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to do the following:

```
header('Location: http://www.someURL.com');
```

But this must be done before anything is dropped to the output steam. Also you would not want to use

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;URL=?".$link."'>";
```

As it would force the browser to reload your page, effectively rendering it useless if the user is trying to click a link or type something just as it refreshes.